# Determining if image exists in Rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I am trying to check if a file exists so that I can either display the image or a placeholder but the placeholder is always shown. If the conditional statement is removed then the logo is displayed fine.

```
<% if File.exists?(Rails.root + '/public/images/portal/logos/' + @organisation_id + '.png') %>
  <img src="/images/portal/logos/<%= @organisation_id %>.png" alt="<%= @person.organisation.name %>">
<% else %>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x83&text=Please+upload+your+company+logo">
<% end %>
```

I've read a few questions but most seem to relate to Rails 3 but seeing as I don't get any errors I thought this would work.

Comment: `Rails.root` is working in rails 2? it may be `RAILS_ROOT`

Comment: just tried printing `Rails.root` and it prints out the correct path, so my image url is fine so not sure why it's not picking it up. `RAILS_ROOT` prints the same path but the image check works, weird. If you submit an answer I will mark it accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rails.root` is working in rails 2? it may be `RAILS_ROOT`

Answer (score 1):

`Rails.root` returns a `Pathname`. Adding an absolute path to a `Pathname` removes the existing path in the `Pathname`.

Ie.

```
Rails.root #=> #<Pathname:/foo/bar>
Rails.root + "baz" #=> #<Pathname:/foo/bar/baz>
Rails.root + "/baz" #=> #<Pathname:/baz>
```

If you do

```
Rails.root + 'public/images/portal/logos/#{@organisation_id}.png'
```

it should work. Or perhaps even better:

```
Rails.root.join("public/images/portal/logos", "#{@organisation_id.png')
```

Compare this to `RAILS_ROOT` which returns a `String`:

```
RAILS_ROOT #=> "/foo/bar"
RAILS_ROOT + "baz" #=> "/foo/barbaz"
RAILS_ROOT + "/baz" #=> "/foo/bar/baz"
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. If I try your suggestions it still doesn't work, maybe because I'm on Rails 2. Seems counter-intuitive to me to leave out the initial forward slash but I guess that's just the magic of Rails. Hopefully someone in the future will benefit from your great explanation though.